# Bootstrap 4 collapsed content is not hiding

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am a beginner and need help. 
I combined the Bootstrap 4 "card deck" with "collapse" to show the information when clicking on a button. My plan was, to show only one content at a time, so if I click another button, it should replace the content. 
Unfortunately, the collapsed content of a button is not hiding, when I click another button, but instead is added underneath.
Please show me the way to fix this.

```
<section id="services-cards" class="section-bg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="card-deck">
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="img/icons/cleaning_icon.svg" alt="Professionelle Zahnreinigung">
                    <div class="card-body" id="bodyOne">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Professionelle Zahnreinigung</h5>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">Preis & Info</a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="img/icons/filling_icon.svg" alt="Zahnfüllung">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Zahnfüllung</h5>
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">Preis & Info</a>
                    </div>
                </div> 

                <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="img/icons/whitening_icon.svg" alt="Zahnaufhellung">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Zahnaufhellung</h5>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">Preis & Info</a>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
            </div>

            <div class="collapse" id="collapseOne">
                <div class="card card-body">
                    <p>Die professionelle Zahnreinigung ist ein wichtiger Beitrag zur Zahnerhaltung, denn selbst regelmäßiges und gründliches Zähneputzen reicht meist nicht aus. 
                        Durch das Entfernen der Zahnbeläge und Zahnstein, wird bakteriell bedingten Erkrankungen wie Karies oder Parodonthose vorgebeugt.</p> 
                    <p>Standardmäßig verwenden wir dabei Scaler, Küretten und Ultraschallgeräte. 
                        Bei starken Verschmutzungen, oder auf Wunsch kommt bei uns auch ein Pulverstrahlgerät (Airflow) zum Einsatz.</p>
                    <h6>900 - 1.500,- THB</h6>                        
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse" id="collapseTwo">
                <div class="card card-body">
                    <p>Mit einer Zahnfüllungen können verschieden Defekte an den Zähnen repariert werden. 
                        Neben Karies oder einem abgebrochenen Stück Zahn werden immer häufiger auch Erosionen durch das Putzen oder durch Säuren, mit Füllungen versorgt.</p>
                    <p>Wir verwenden dafür ausschließlich zahnfarbene Kunststofffüllunegn (Composite), welche in den kaputten Zahn eingebracht und mit einem speziellen Licht ausgehärtet werden.</p>
                    <h6>1.200,- THB</h6>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse" id="collapseThree">
                <div class="card card-body">
                    <p>Unter dem Bleaching oder dem Aufhellen von Zähnen versteht man entweder die Wiederherstellung oder die Aufhellung der natürlichen Zahnfarbe, 
                        mithilfe von Bleichungsmitteln.</p>
                    <p>Nach einer vorangegangenen, professionellen Zahnreinigung wird das Zahnfleisch mit einem Silikon abgedeckt und das Bleichmittel (Wasserstoffperoxid) 
                        auf den Zahn aufgetragen. Um die Behandlung zu beschleunigen, diese dabei aber so schmerzfrei wie möglich zu gestalten, verwenden wir eine spezielle Halogenlampe.</p>                 
                    <h6>5.900,- THB</h6>
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>      
    </section>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49645228/bootstrap-4-collapse-other-sections-when-one-is-expanded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply using `data-parent` attribute:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="accordion">
  <section id="services-cards" class="section-bg">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="img/icons/cleaning_icon.svg" alt="Professionelle Zahnreinigung">
          <div class="card-body" id="bodyOne">
            <h5 class="card-title">Professionelle Zahnreinigung</h5>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">Preis & Info</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="img/icons/filling_icon.svg" alt="Zahnfüllung">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Zahnfüllung</h5>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">Preis & Info</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="img/icons/whitening_icon.svg" alt="Zahnaufhellung">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Zahnaufhellung</h5>
            <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseThree" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">Preis & Info</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="collapseOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card card-body">
          <p>Die professionelle Zahnreinigung ist ein wichtiger Beitrag zur Zahnerhaltung, denn selbst regelmäßiges und gründliches Zähneputzen reicht meist nicht aus. Durch das Entfernen der Zahnbeläge und Zahnstein, wird bakteriell bedingten Erkrankungen
            wie Karies oder Parodonthose vorgebeugt.</p>
          <p>Standardmäßig verwenden wir dabei Scaler, Küretten und Ultraschallgeräte. Bei starken Verschmutzungen, oder auf Wunsch kommt bei uns auch ein Pulverstrahlgerät (Airflow) zum Einsatz.</p>
          <h6>900 - 1.500,- THB</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse" id="collapseTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card card-body">
          <p>Mit einer Zahnfüllungen können verschieden Defekte an den Zähnen repariert werden. Neben Karies oder einem abgebrochenen Stück Zahn werden immer häufiger auch Erosionen durch das Putzen oder durch Säuren, mit Füllungen versorgt.</p>
          <p>Wir verwenden dafür ausschließlich zahnfarbene Kunststofffüllunegn (Composite), welche in den kaputten Zahn eingebracht und mit einem speziellen Licht ausgehärtet werden.</p>
          <h6>1.200,- THB</h6>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse" id="collapseThree" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card card-body">
          <p>Unter dem Bleaching oder dem Aufhellen von Zähnen versteht man entweder die Wiederherstellung oder die Aufhellung der natürlichen Zahnfarbe, mithilfe von Bleichungsmitteln.</p>
          <p>Nach einer vorangegangenen, professionellen Zahnreinigung wird das Zahnfleisch mit einem Silikon abgedeckt und das Bleichmittel (Wasserstoffperoxid) auf den Zahn aufgetragen. Um die Behandlung zu beschleunigen, diese dabei aber so schmerzfrei
            wie möglich zu gestalten, verwenden wir eine spezielle Halogenlampe.</p>
          <h6>5.900,- THB</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I played with data-parent and the accordion but was not able to solve it. Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

I believe that bootstrap does not support this out of the box.
You can accomplish this with a tiny bit of javascript:

```
$('.btn-primary').on('click', function() {
  $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

I made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/90q1nv2u/) to show this working.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the solution of Yi-Ting Liu was the one I was searching for.