# Angular Bootstrap Collapse: How to Close One Collapse When Another Collapse Opens

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am fairly new to Angular, and in my project I am using regular Bootstrap. I have a few collapse buttons on my page, and I would like to make it so only one collapse is open at a time. If a user opens one collapse, then clicks the button for the next, the first should close in response.

Is this possible? I'm having a hard time finding any solutions to this. Any advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the `data-parent` attribute!

Here is already a similar question, look at the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49645462/9544229

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much! Exactly what I was looking for!